# Stop a view in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-linearlayout

I have a view with a keyboard, like this:

```
     mInputView = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.input_left, null);
        panel = (ImageView) mInputView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        panel.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked " ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editor.putBoolean("panel", true);
            mKeyboardView.closing();

            return true;
            }
        });
```

I want to stopping the view, but I cannot do this in this way

Comment: what do you mean by stopping the view?

Comment: I did this with my_view.setVisibility, but after that I want to change layout...